# Azure Functions Postgres ID violation error on auto increment ID

Tags: python, postgresql, azure-functions

I have an Azure function that retrieve data from API and save it to Postgres DB. Now I have this returning error with duplicated ID

> Error occurred during database operation: duplicate key value violates
> unique constraint 'contacts_pkey' DETAIL:  Key (id)=(12736022) already
> exists.

Here is my insert statement in function

```
def process_contacts(dbString, data, db_table_contacts):
    sql_contacts = f"""INSERT INTO {db_table_contacts}(uuid, name, age, gender, .....)
          VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, .....)
          ON CONFLICT (uuid) DO UPDATE SET
```

I'm processing records in batches of 250 per transaction. Here is also my constrain in Postgres

[image: postgres contrains]

What I'm missing here, records are autocimeneting on ID and should update set when there is duplicate ?

Comment: This seems fine. Something else must be messing with the table - inserting rows with explicit keys. Try to prevent explicit keys with `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Below are the steps I followed:**

- A function `process_contacts` is defined. It consists of three arguments **dbString**, **data**, **Bnewcontacts**.
- **dbString** is used to determine a connection to the PostgreSQL database. **data** is used to store the data present in the database.
- using `uuid.uuid4()` a new UUID is generated for every contact.
- `sql_contacts` consists of SQL statement which contains **INSERT** statement with **ON CONFLICT** clause.
- By using `ON CONFLICT` if a record with same **id** already exists in the table, it will be updated with the new values. I tried same in the code below. In your code, you are trying to insert **id** which is already present in your db but `ON CONFLICT` is used on **uuid**. I tried with the same and it gives the same error what you showed in the above.

```py
def process_contacts(dbString, data, BnewContacts):
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(dbString)
        cur = conn.cursor()

        for record in data:
            id_val, name, age, gender = record
            
            uuid_value = uuid.uuid4()
            
            uuid_str = str(uuid_value)
            
            sql_contacts = """INSERT INTO BnewContacts(id, uuid, name, age, gender)
                              VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
                              ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET
                              uuid = EXCLUDED.uuid,
                              name = EXCLUDED.name,
                              age = EXCLUDED.age,
                              gender = EXCLUDED.gender
                           """
            cur.execute(sql_contacts, (id_val, uuid_str, name, age, gender))  # Exclude the id column

        
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        print("Data successfully inserted or updated.")
    except Exception as e:
        
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        
data = [
    (1, 'Sai', 24, 'Male'),
    (2, 'Venkatesh', 18, 'Male')
    ]
dbString = "dbname=citus user=**** password=**** host=****"
db_table_contacts = "BnewContacts"

process_contacts(dbString, data, db_table_contacts)
```

**Output:**

```
Data successfully inserted or updated.
```

```
id |                 uuid                 |   name    | age | gender 
----+--------------------------------------+-----------+-----+--------
  1 | f8c694f2-2fd4-420b-8fac-483b6d4f3c13 | Sai       |  14 | Male
  2 | 00e3078a-13df-4ff8-865c-4fcac5ff9f26 | Venkatesh |  28 | Male
(2 rows)

citus=> SELECT * FROM BnewContacts;
 id |                 uuid                 |   name    | age | gender 
----+--------------------------------------+-----------+-----+--------
  1 | 5fec84e0-b9da-4ed1-a9f7-ceb156bc0ccb | Sai       |  24 | Male
  2 | 576f0a6a-82bf-401d-b1ad-38fcd5a3987f | Venkatesh |  18 | Male
```

- using `ON CONFLICT` I tried to insert the data which is already exists in the db. **Age** values has been updated in the above output.
- For further on **ON CONFLICT** refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/how-to-use-pgvector).